# f# cast obj to tuple type from FSharpValue.MakeTuple

Tags: types, casting, f#

I have an `obj` which is actually a tuple `DateTime*int*decimal*decimal`, it is an `obj`, because I create the `tuple` by using,

```
let tupleType = typeof<(DateTime*int*decimal*decimal)>
let ret = FSharpValue.MakeTuple(x, tupleType)
```

Now I would like to cast `ret` backto `DateTime*int*decimal*decimal`, I did,

```
 ret :?> DateTime*int*decimal*decimal
```

My question is can I use `tupleType` to do the casting instead of specifying the type explicitly as in the above code?

.

Comment: This starts to get very complicated and can't be done easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it the way you expected, as Mark explained in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35911918/917053). However, what you can do is using [type abbreviation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233246.aspx):

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

type MyTuple = DateTime*int*decimal*decimal

let ret = FSharpValue.MakeTuple([|DateTime.Now;1;1.0M;1.0M|],typeof<MyTuple>)
let myTuple = ret :?> MyTuple
```

getting `myTuple` of type `MyTuple`, where the latter carries type information about tuple consituents at *compile time*.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is **no**.

Casting and type checking happens already at compile-time. It's called *static typing* because the types are independent of the run-time (dynamic) values. The types are already available when the code isn't running (i.e. is *static*).

At compile-time, `ret` has the static type `obj`, while at run-time it has the type `DateTime*int*decimal*decimal`.

The compiler, however, doesn't know this unless you tell it.

Likewise, `tupleType` has the type `Type` at both compile-time and run-time. It's *value*, however, is `DateTime*int*decimal*decimal`. That information is only available at run-time.

If you want `ret` to have the type `DateTime*int*decimal*decimal`, you'll need to tell the compiler that this is the type. At compile-time, `tupleType` doesn't provide that information.

If you can design your system so that you don't need to use Reflection, you can probably stay type-safe, so if that's at all possible, it'd probably be a better option.